# Función con recursión que devuelva string invertido

Tags: javascript, recursión

Me piden hacer una función con recursión, que reciba como argumento un string y lo devuelva invertido.

Esto es lo que he hecho:

```js
function alRevesRec(str) {
  if (str.length === 0) {
    return;
  } else {
    let pal = [];
    let arr = str.split(' ');
    pal = arr.pop(); /*con shift el resultado es el mismo*/
    alRevesRec(arr);
    return pal;
  }

}
console.log(alRevesRec('dePaTras')) /*imprime 'dePaTras',debería ser 'sarTaPed'*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en tu código, por ejemplo:

```
 let arr = str.split(' ');
```

Esta línea separa la cadena por espacios. Vos necesitarías separarla por caracteres.

```
 return pal;
```

Esta línea devuelve lo primero que obtenes. Te estaría faltando a agregar lo que devuelve la llamada recursiva al resultado.

#### Solución:

Podrías corregir tu código así:

```js
function alRevesRec(str) {
  if (str.length === 0)
    return ''; // Devolvemos una cadena vacia

  let arr = str.split(''); // Separamos por caracteres
  let pal = arr.pop();
  // Devolvemos el ultimo caracter mas el resultado de la llamada recursiva
  return pal + alRevesRec(arr.join(''));
}
console.log(alRevesRec('dePaTras'))
```

También podrías hacerlo así:

```js
function alRevesRec(str) {
  // No hay mas caracteres
  if (!str.length) return '';

  // Obtenemos el último caracter de la cadena
  let char = str.substr(-1);
  
  // A la cadena le sacamos el ultimo caracter
  let newStr = str.substr(0, str.length - 1);
  
  // Devolvemos el último caracter más lo que obtengamos
  // de la llamda recursiva para el resto de la cadena
  return char + alRevesRec(newStr);
}
console.log(alRevesRec('dePaTras'))
```

O así (*que es exactamente lo mismo que antes*)

```js
function alRevesRec(str) {
  return str.length ? str.substr(-1) + alRevesRec(str.substr(0, str.length - 1)) : '';
}
console.log(alRevesRec('dePaTras'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Algo mucho más fácil, el `string` que recibe tu función (que es convertido en array con `split('')`) extraes al último elemento y a ese último lo conviertes en cadena para luego concatenarlo con el siguiente último elemento de tu llamada recursiva, ya que la siguiente te devuelve nuevamente el último elemento del array.

Para que entiendas mejor, imagina que tu array es este:

```
["d", "e", "P", "a", "T", "r", "a", "s"]
```

Extraes al último con `pop()` y tienes:

```
s
```

Y luego concatenas eso con el resultado de tu función cuando lo llamas nuevamente, ya que en la siguiente llamada, tu array queda así:

```
["d", "e", "P", "a", "T", "r", "a"]
```

Extraes a ese último nuevamente y al concatenarlo tienes:

```
sa
```

Así sucesivamente hasta tener todos los elementos del arreglo de manera inversa.

Ejemplo:

```js
function alRevesRec(str) {
  if (str.length === 0) {
    return ""; // Si la cadena está vacía, devolvemos una cadena vacía.
  } else {
    let arr = str.split(''); // Convertimos en un array a la cadena, en donde cada caracter es un elemento del array...
    let ultimo = arr.pop(); // Luego extraigo el último elemento del array...
    let resto = arr.join(''); // Luego convierto el resto del arreglo en una cadena...
    return ultimo + alRevesRec(resto); // Y por último concateno el último carácter con la llamada recursiva.
  }
}

console.log(alRevesRec('dePaTras'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes user metodos de arrays para hacerlo sencillo

```
function alRevesRec(str) {
if(str == '') return '';
return str.split('').reverse().join('')
}
```

recibes cadena, si es vacía, devuelves vacío (personaliza)
Si no, devuelve la cadena volteada
el método split separa la cadena en un arreglo, el reverse, voltea el arreglo, y el join, vuelve a unir el arreglo devolviéndote la cadena volteada

Comment: Cómo? solo estoy ofreciendo una alternativa, no veo el problema, y que tiene que ver ChatGPT?

Comment: La pregunta pide expicitamente recursion ;)